# Javascript Regex format

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I want to check if the input matches this format:

```
format: "dd/MM/yyyy"
```

Of course they would have to me numbers.  What is the regex expression, and/or jquery/javascript function that i'd use to make sure this input matches this?

Comment: Do you want to ensure it's in that format and/or a valid date?

Comment: No suggestions yet, so nothing.

Comment: valid date would be much better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var matches = str.search(/^\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}$/) > -1;
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
/^[0123]?\d\/[01]?\d\/\d{2,}$/
```

Remember that only certain numbers are valid months and days.

Other approaches can be found at the [Regular Expression Library](http://regexlib.com/Search.aspx?k=&c=5).

Answer (score 0):

If you just wanted to check the format, and not if it's actually a valid date, the following should work:

```
/\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}/
```